# how to remove chr from vcf file using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I need to remove 'chr' from my vcf file. This is the aspect of the vcf file:

```
#CHROM  POS  
chr1   10570
chr1   10574
chr1   10654
```

I want to have the following one

```
#CHROM  POS  
   1   10570
   1   10574
   1   10654
```

I have tried several ways like the following ones:

```
awk '{gsub(/^chr/,""); print}' your.vcf > no_chr.vcf
sed 's/^chr//'
sed 's:chr::g'
awk '{gsub(/\chr/, "")}1'
perl -pe  's/^chr//g'
sed '/^##/! s/chr//'
```

but they don't work...any suggestion?
Thank you!

Comment: *they don't work* we need more information, if you did `awk '{gsub(/^chr/,""); print}' your.vcf > no_chr.vcf` please add result file (`no_chr.vcf`) or if it is too big, at least few first lines, also what exactly version of AWK are you using (you might check it by doing `awk --version`)?

Comment: GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.6-p2, GNU MP 6.1.2) this is the awk version. It doesn't work means actually that I still have chr...so my output file remains equal to my input

Comment: Are there any (possibly, special) characters at the beginning of the line, before each `chr`? That would explain why `perl -pe  's/^chr//g'` does not work in your case.

Comment: Try `cat -vet YOURFILE.VCF` to see any weird characters.

Comment: @MarkSetchell FYI `cat -A` is equivalent to `cat -vet`.

Comment: @EdMorton Ok, thanks for the heads up. The `cat` that Apple ships doesn't support that option - and I also find I can easily remember cats and vets 

Answer (score 4):

For beginners it is much better to use dedicated tools rather than unix tools. It's easy to end up messing up your file.

```
echo "chr1 1" >> rename_chrs.txt
bcftools annotate --rename-chrs rename_chrs.txt in.vcf > out.vcf
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with 3 spaces.

```
sed 's/^chr/   /' your.vcf > no_chr.vcf
```

Comment: no I still have chr using this command :(

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/E2y87E

Comment: Are you sure `chr` is at the beginning of the line, with no spaces before it?

Comment: Check the file with a hex dump to make sure there aren't any invisible characters, and `chr` is ordinary ASCII.

Comment: yeah the line starts with chr1 without any space/symbol...i don't know why nothing works for my file

Comment: @Khaleesi95 based on all of your comments and attempts it's 100% clear that your lines do NOT start with `chr`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -pe  's/^chr//' your.vcf
```

And if you want to remove all `chr` anywhere in the line:

```
perl -i.bak -pe  's/chr//g' your.vcf
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

`s/^chr//` : Replace `chr` at the beginning of the string (here, the line) with an empty string. There is no need to use the `g` modifier (match the pattern repeatedly), since there is only one replacement per line.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

---

**Complete example with input and output:**

Create test input:

```
cat > your.vcf <<EOF
#CHROM  POS  
chr1   10570
chr1   10574
chr1   10654
EOF
```

Confirm using `cat` and `hexdump` that there are no special characters:

```
cat your.vcf
```

Prints:

```
#CHROM  POS  
chr1   10570
chr1   10574
chr1   10654
```

```
hexdump -C your.vcf
```

Prints:

```
00000000  23 43 48 52 4f 4d 20 20  50 4f 53 20 20 0a 63 68  |#CHROM  POS  .ch|
00000010  72 31 20 20 20 31 30 35  37 30 0a 63 68 72 31 20  |r1   10570.chr1 |
00000020  20 20 31 30 35 37 34 0a  63 68 72 31 20 20 20 31  |  10574.chr1   1|
00000030  30 36 35 34 0a                                    |0654.|
00000035
```

Remove `chr`:

```
perl -i.bak -pe  's/^chr//' your.vcf
```

Check the file:

```
cat your.vcf
```

Prints:

```
#CHROM  POS  
1   10570
1   10574
1   10654
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/^#/! {:a;s/[a-z]([0-9])?/ \1/;ta}' input_file
#CHROM  POS
   1   10570
   1   10574
   1   10654
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what it's doing. I don't see how this looks specifically for `chr`.

Comment: Apparently this is replacing all the letters before the first digit with spaces.

Comment: neither this command line works... :(

Answer (score 0):

When editing VCF files with `awk` I've found it easier to specify the column rather than using regex since the first 8 columns of VCF files are fixed (#CHROM, POS, ID, REF, ALT, QUAL, FILTER, INFO).

Here's a solution with `awk` that substitute `"chr"` with `""` in column 1. (I used `sub()` here rather than `gsub()` since there's only one instance of `"chr"` to replace for each line.)

```
awk '{ sub("chr", "", $1); print }' your.vcf > no_chr.vcf
```

**Note that this code can change your delimiter.** By default `awk` uses whitespace as the input field separator and a single space as the output field separator.

Most VCF files I've worked with are tab-delimited. In order to use tab as the delimiter for both input and output, you need to specify the input field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) at the beginning of your code.

Here's the same solution using tab as the field separator:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } { sub("chr", "", $1); print }' your.vcf > no_chr.vcf
```